# Query list in a service method and return results to component?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am having an issue with returning a set of data from a firestore query back to a calling component that needs the data. I have a component that injects a service class in which I want to do all my DB connection/querying on a firestore backend. The method in the service is as follows and works perfectly to retrieve the records I want:

```
getCardsByUserId(userId: string) {

    return this.afs.firestore.collection('cards').where('uid', '==', userId).get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {

            if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
                let cards: Card[];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

                    // THIS DISPLAY EACH ROW CORRECTLY - now how do I pass it back to my component?
                    console.log(doc, " => ", doc.data());

                    // trying to create an object Card put 'push' and return
                    const card = new Card(
                        doc.data().name,
                        doc.data().description,
                        doc.data().imagePath,
                        doc.data().ingredients
                    );
                    cards.push(card);

                });
                //console.log('BEFORE RETUNR', cards);
                return cards;
            } else {
                return [];
            }

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

}
```

In my component I successfully inject the service and call the getCardsByUserId() method in ngOnit (this cards is a property declares as `cards: Card[];`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // need to get the cards by user's id

    //console.log(this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid);
    const userId = this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid;
    this.cardService.getCardsByUserId(userId).then(cards => {
        console.log('RESULTS', cards);
        this.cards = cards;
    });
}
```

However the component is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/dashboard/dashboard-section/my-cards/card-list/card-list.component.ts(33,13): error TS2322: Type 'void | Card[]' is not assignable to type 'Card[]'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Card[]'.
```

I have tried these approaches but something gets lost in translation in the service method:

```
return querySnapshot.doc;
```

====

```
const cards = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   cards.push(doc.data());
}
return cards;
```

Ideally I want getCardsByUserId() to return an array of the objects found...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the data on your component you could return the observable on the **getCurrentUser** function and then on your component you can subscribe and read it as needed.

```
return this.afs.collection('cards', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', userId)).valueChanges();
```

Then when you need to read the observable just do it like this:

```
dataList.subscribe(list => {
  console.log(list)
}
```

I really recommend you read the official [Angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md).

Comment: Thank you for your help.....can you explain how you came up with 

`return this.afs.collection('cards', ref => ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId)).valueChanges();`

I am getting error 'property orderByChild does not exist on type CollectionReference - also I do not see orderByChild in the documentation you linked to above.....

Comment: I'm sorry, I did it from memory and mixed the Realtime Database query sintax. I just updated it to match the docs.

Comment: Thank you this is getting me closer. I have an issue and this is where the documentation in my opinion does not seem at all clear - with .valueChanges() you do not get get the record ID - I need the ID for the records. I know I have to use .snapshotChanges() but how can I make this code return an observable? Are you familiar with that? Thank you.

Comment: I need to add that when I use snapshotChanges() i DO get an observable but the data is not "organized" and "clean" like it is with valueChanges() - looks like it need to be formatted a certain way.

Comment: Yeah, I've encountered this problem before many times and it seems there is no better answer. I usually just subscribe to snapshotChanges and get the key and then I use that key in a regular valueChanges query. If you get a better way to do that I would appreciate if you could share it!

Answer (score 0):

AntonioGarcia thanks for your help...this is what I did to get what I wanted after you pointed me in the right direction:

In service method:

```
getCardsByUserId(userId: string) {

        // old realtime firebase way:
        // return this.afs.collection('cards', ref => ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId)).valueChanges();
        // NEW firestore way:
        return this.afs.collection('cards', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', userId)).snapshotChanges();
}
```

In my component:

```
this.subscription = this.cardService.getCardsByUserId(userId)
            .subscribe(cards => {
                this.cards = cards.map(a => {
                    const card: Card = a.payload.doc.data() as Card;
                    card.id = a.payload.doc.id;

                    return card;
                });
            }
```